# Translate behaviour (query timing out)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a model:

```
class Product extends AppModel {    
    var $actsAs=array(      
        'Translate' => array(
        'title', 'excerpt', 'overview', 'construction', 'options', 'features', 'benefits'
        )
    );      
}
```

In my controller I'm querying:

```
$this->Product->findPublic('all');
```

it seems the default behaviour is to add an alias for each translated field in the query as its own table, for example:

```
SELECT `Product`.*, `I18n__title`.`content`, `I18n__excerpt`.`content`, `I18n__overview`.`content`, `I18n__construction`.`content`, `I18n__options`.`content`, `I18n__features`.`content`, `I18n__benefits`.`content` FROM `ck_products` AS `Product` LEFT JOIN `ck_i18n` AS `I18n__title` ON (`Product`.`id` = `I18n__title`.`foreign_key` AND `I18n__title`.`model` = 'Product' AND `I18n__title`.`field` = 'title') LEFT JOIN `ck_i18n` AS `I18n__excerpt` ON (`Product`.`id` = `I18n__excerpt`.`foreign_key` AND `I18n__excerpt`.`model` = 'Product' AND `I18n__excerpt`.`field` = 'excerpt') LEFT JOIN `ck_i18n` AS `I18n__overview` ON (`Product`.`id` = `I18n__overview`.`foreign_key` AND `I18n__overview`.`model` = 'Product' AND `I18n__overview`.`field` = 'overview') LEFT JOIN `ck_i18n` AS `I18n__construction` ON (`Product`.`id` = `I18n__construction`.`foreign_key` AND `I18n__construction`.`model` = 'Product' AND `I18n__construction`.`field` = 'construction') LEFT JOIN `ck_i18n` AS `I18n__options` ON (`Product`.`id` = `I18n__options`.`foreign_key` AND `I18n__options`.`model` = 'Product' AND `I18n__options`.`field` = 'options') LEFT JOIN `ck_i18n` AS `I18n__features` ON (`Product`.`id` = `I18n__features`.`foreign_key` AND `I18n__features`.`model` = 'Product' AND `I18n__features`.`field` = 'features') LEFT JOIN `ck_i18n` AS `I18n__benefits` ON (`Product`.`id` = `I18n__benefits`.`foreign_key` AND `I18n__benefits`.`model` = 'Product' AND `I18n__benefits`.`field` = 'benefits')  WHERE `Product`.`status` = 'active' AND NOT (`Product`.`slug` = '') AND `I18n__title`.`locale` = 'eng' AND `I18n__excerpt`.`locale` = 'eng' AND `I18n__overview`.`locale` = 'eng' AND `I18n__construction`.`locale` = 'eng' AND `I18n__options`.`locale` = 'eng' AND `I18n__features`.`locale` = 'eng' AND `I18n__benefits`.`locale` = 'eng'
```

The more fields I add, the slower my query gets. In fact, it's now timing out.
Is there a better way to do this in Cake?

Comment: That's the main reason I never use this behavior, IMO it's just too inefficient. As an alternative, we developed an in-house solution that uses a translation table for each model/table that is translatable. Basically, a 'shadow' table, containing translations for each records. Records that do not have a translation can either be omitted, or falling back to the default/main language. Translations can be stored in a separate table, or in the same table, using a locale-column to specify the language.

Comment: Just been chatting to a colleague about this issue that he's having and made a suggestion pretty much exactly like @thaJeztah's so it was interesting to find it here on my first search. This seems like a good approach as Cake's Translate behaviour is a real pain to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive used behaviours to only return some of the fields which solves my issue:

```
$this->Product->Behaviors->attach('Translate', array('title'));
```

I'd still be insterested in the answer if you had, say, 20 translated fields and require them all listed in a single view.